# GoogleTrans Python not translating

Tags: python, google-translate, googletrans

I am using GoogleTrans for my project. Actually I have a text in Marathi which I got from "speech to text" but when I am converting that text into English it is not translating properLY.

But when I am using Google Translate from website, it is translating properly with 100% accuracy ?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72Ep4.png)

Here is the piece of Code :

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from cltk.corpus.utils.importer import CorpusImporter
from googletrans import Translator
import goslate
import googletrans

print("Hello World")

filename = r"C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Documents\Mini Project-2 (Trimester 4)\Project 1- (Document Summary)\Dataset\Voice\Gaurav.wav"
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:
    audio_data = r.record(source)

    text = r.recognize_google(audio_data,language='mr')
    print("Text\n",text)

    print(type(text))
    
    translator = Translator()
    converted_text = translator.translate(text)
    print("Converted text\n",converted_text)

    with open("D:/output.txt",'w',encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(text)
        f.write(str(converted_text))
```

Please suggest, what should I do?

Comment: you may want to check the deep_translator package: https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep_translator

Answer (score 6):

https://pypi.org/project/googletrans is an unofficial package (not created by Google). Also in the disclaimer, it has the following "*...this API does not guarantee that the library would work properly at all times...*". If you want stability, use official Google API https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs

Anyway below is a test to show the translator **work**:

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()
results =translator.translate('हॅलो वर्ल्ड')
print(results.text)
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

I'm not sure what the issue you're experiencing. However I would suggest refactoring your code into methods and then you can test in isolation.

The code below has **not** been tested, but should help debug:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
#from cltk.corpus.utils.importer import CorpusImporter
from googletrans import Translator
#import goslate
#import googletrans

def provideAudioToText(filename):
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:
    audio_data = r.record(source)
    return r.recognize_google(audio_data,language='mr')

def translate(text):
    translator = Translator()
    results = translator.translate(text)
    return results.text

def Save(filename, original_text, converted_text):
    with open(filename,'w',encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(original_text)
        f.write(str(converted_text))

original_text = provideAudioToText(r"C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Documents\Mini Project-2 (Trimester 4)\Project 1- (Document Summary)\Dataset\Voice\Gaurav.wav")
print("Text\n", original_text)
print(type(original_text))
converted_text = translate(original_text)
print("Converted text\n",converted_text)
Save("D:/output.txt", original_text, converted_text)
```

Comment: see this: https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/python-code-text-google-translate-website-translation-beautifulsoup-library.html

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade your googletrans module as below.

```
pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1
```

I see the default installation googletrans uses the 3.x version and it has the problems that you mentioned above.

See the conversation on [Github page](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/234)

Answer (score 0):

had same issue with 3.0.0, worked with latest version . **4.0.0rc1**