# googletrans - Getting output same as input

Tags: python, google-translate, googletrans

I am trying to translate from AWS EC2 Instance with googletrans python library using below snippet:

```
translator = Translator(service_urls=['translate.google.com', 'translate.google.co.kr'])
translated_text = str(translator.translate("你好!", dest="en").text)

print(translated_text) # <------- outputs to 你好! but it should be ideally Hello there
```

The same code was working for 6+ months at same instance, but from last 2-3 days , I am getting output same as input.
I checked it **translate.google.com** , it was working fine, so thought it would be a bug with googletrans

**Current Behaviour:**

Suppose if I want to translate 你好! to English , At Output , I am getting same value "你好!" - before that it converts to "Hello there".

Even for Single text, this is happening. Any help appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I believe this might be a duplicate [of this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64867159). As mentioned in my other comment, please consider using [Google API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup#installing_client_libraries) for stable supported results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GoogleTrans Python not translating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63077115/googletrans-python-not-translating)

Comment: It does help - Thanks! @SergiMuñoz