# googletrans stopped working with detecting all languages as English

Tags: python, google-translate, google-translation-api, googletrans

The problem I have here is googletrans API suddenly stopped working, just like this:

```
result = translator.translate('祝您新年快乐', src='zh-cn', dest='en')
result.text
```

Output:

```
'祝您新年快乐'
```

It should return English but just printed the original text. Then I checked what goes wrong. I found that googletrans detect all languages as english, like this:

```
print(translator.detect('이 문장은 한글로 쓰여졌습니다.'))
print(translator.detect('祝您新年快乐'))
```

Output:

```
Detected(lang=en, confidence=1)
Detected(lang=en, confidence=1)
```

Finally I checked if those languages are available in the library. It is.

```
print(googletrans.LANGUAGES)
```

output:

```
{'af': 'afrikaans', 'sq': 'albanian', 'am': 'amharic', 'ar': 'arabic', 'hy': 'armenian', 'az': 'azerbaijani', 'eu': 'basque', 'be': 'belarusian', 'bn': 'bengali', 'bs': 'bosnian', 'bg': 'bulgarian', 'ca': 'catalan', 'ceb': 'cebuano', 'ny': 'chichewa', 'zh-cn': 'chinese (simplified)', 'zh-tw': 'chinese (traditional)', 'co': 'corsican', 'hr': 'croatian', 'cs': 'czech', 'da': 'danish', 'nl': 'dutch', 'en': 'english', 'eo': 'esperanto', 'et': 'estonian', 'tl': 'filipino', 'fi': 'finnish', 'fr': 'french', 'fy': 'frisian', 'gl': 'galician', 'ka': 'georgian', 'de': 'german', 'el': 'greek', 'gu': 'gujarati', 'ht': 'haitian creole', 'ha': 'hausa', 'haw': 'hawaiian', 'iw': 'hebrew', 'he': 'hebrew', 'hi': 'hindi', 'hmn': 'hmong', 'hu': 'hungarian', 'is': 'icelandic', 'ig': 'igbo', 'id': 'indonesian', 'ga': 'irish', 'it': 'italian', 'ja': 'japanese', 'jw': 'javanese', 'kn': 'kannada', 'kk': 'kazakh', 'km': 'khmer', 'ko': 'korean', 'ku': 'kurdish (kurmanji)', 'ky': 'kyrgyz', 'lo': 'lao', 'la': 'latin', 'lv': 'latvian', 'lt': 'lithuanian', 'lb': 'luxembourgish', 'mk': 'macedonian', 'mg': 'malagasy', 'ms': 'malay', 'ml': 'malayalam', 'mt': 'maltese', 'mi': 'maori', 'mr': 'marathi', 'mn': 'mongolian', 'my': 'myanmar (burmese)', 'ne': 'nepali', 'no': 'norwegian', 'or': 'odia', 'ps': 'pashto', 'fa': 'persian', 'pl': 'polish', 'pt': 'portuguese', 'pa': 'punjabi', 'ro': 'romanian', 'ru': 'russian', 'sm': 'samoan', 'gd': 'scots gaelic', 'sr': 'serbian', 'st': 'sesotho', 'sn': 'shona', 'sd': 'sindhi', 'si': 'sinhala', 'sk': 'slovak', 'sl': 'slovenian', 'so': 'somali', 'es': 'spanish', 'su': 'sundanese', 'sw': 'swahili', 'sv': 'swedish', 'tg': 'tajik', 'ta': 'tamil', 'te': 'telugu', 'th': 'thai', 'tr': 'turkish', 'uk': 'ukrainian', 'ur': 'urdu', 'ug': 'uyghur', 'uz': 'uzbek', 'vi': 'vietnamese', 'cy': 'welsh', 'xh': 'xhosa', 'yi': 'yiddish', 'yo': 'yoruba', 'zu': 'zulu'}
```

Can someone help here by explaning why this problem happened all of a sudden? It works just 30 minutes ago. It's weird it stopped working without changing anything.

Comment: Have you read the disclaimer on their documents: https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/ `Due to limitations of the web version of google translate, this API does not guarantee that the library would work`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation `googletrans`, https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/, *"is an unofficial library using the web API of translate.google.com"*.

They specifically state:

> Due to limitations of the web version of google translate, this API does not guarantee that the library would work properly at all times (so please use this library **if you don’t care about stability**)

and suggest to use the official Google Translate API (click [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs)).

---

For **further reading** I highly suggest the following sources:

- [GoogleTrans Python not translating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63077115/googletrans-python-not-translating)
- https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/
- https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- If you decide to switch to the **official API** check out: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs